# Как сделать из списка строку, оставляя название переменной?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть переменная с именем `example`, тип этой переменной `list` мне надо преобразовать эту переменную в строковой тип сохраняя имя. в этом списке все значения строки, только необходимо, чтобы всё это было строкой и значения разделены пробелами.

Comment: `example = " ".join(example)`

Comment: спасибо, помогло